# for loop counter with Twig or Swig

Tags: node.js, twig

Anyone know of a clean way to do this in Twig/Swig:

```
{% for(i = 0; i < 100; i++) %}
    blah....
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: [Didn't you trust twig docs?](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html)

Comment: To be honest I assumed Swig to be a complete port of Twig - evidently it's not. I am using Swig and only looked at those docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For twig its:

```
{% for i in 0..100 %}
    * {{ i }}
{% endfor %}
```

From http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html

For swig the docs dont mention it yet:
https://github.com/paularmstrong/swig/blob/master/docs/tags.md#for

i cant really tell but it might be not supported in swig since its django inspired and django  also seems to lack this feature nativly: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/5172

so i would like to pass the swig part to the next one.

Comment: It seems swig doesn't support this feature. I will mark as answer since that works for Twig. Thanks

Answer (score 15):

If you have a number, then you can just convert this to an array and then use Swig's standard for tag. This is simplest if you always want to 'start' the loop from 0 though.

For example:

```
{% set productCount = 6 %}
{% set productCountAsArray = Array(productCount) %}

{# This will run productCount times #}
{% for x, y in productCountAsArray %}
    This is for number: {{ x }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Great answer. Worked for me.I just have one question. Why are two variables, namely `x` and `y` used in the for-loop? Is it because `x` acts as the Array counter and `y` stores the content of the array?

Comment: Thanks, I used this in SWIG.
My OCD kicked in and I trimmed it to the following though:

```{% for i in Array(30) %}blah....{% endfor %}```

Answer (score 8):

The swig docs have since (ivoba's answer) been updated and now contain `special loop variables`, which include `loop.index`:

```
{% for x in y %}
  {% if loop.first %}<ul>{% endif %}
  <li>{{ loop.index }} - {{ loop.key }}: {{ x }}</li>
  {% if loop.last %}</ul>{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

http://paularmstrong.github.io/swig/docs/#tags-for