# Swig - for loop sequence

Tags: javascript, gulp, swig-template

I am using swig in gulp. Swig is a port of Twig.
I would like to iterate over a sequence of digits in Swig for-loop.
Something like:

```
{% for x in 1..10 %}
    <img src="image{{ x }}.jpg" />
{% endfor %}
```

My current workaround is to declare:

```
{% set pictures = [1,2,3,4,5,6] %}
{% for x in picture %}
    <img src="image{{ x }}.jpg" />
{% endfor %}
```

There must be better way to do it :)

Comment: If you just want to loop 10 times, can you just use a normal for loop rather than a for in?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [for loop counter with Twig or Swig](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12102742/for-loop-counter-with-twig-or-swig)

Comment: In Twig maybe this code is possible but looks like in Swig it is not. I found out Swig is not supported by the author anymore and he suggests to use nunjucks.